# Django urls with empty values

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have a django app where i am making calls to the api as follows: `(api.py)`

```
class studentList(APIView):
    def get(self, request, pk, pk2, format=None):
        student_detail = Student.objects.filter(last_name = pk, campus_id__name = pk2)
        serialized_student_detail = studentSerializer(student_detail, many=True)
        return Response(serialized_student_detail.data)
```

and in the urls i am doing something like follows:

```
url(r'^api/student/(?P<pk>.+)/(?P<pk2>.+)/$', api.studentList.as_view()),
```

Now the problem is that my app has a **search** function where it sends the parameters `pk` and `pk2` to the api. Sometimes, the user may select only 1 of these parameters to perform **search** operation . So when only one parameter is selected, the url would look something like this:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/student/##value of pk//
```

or

```
http://localhost:8000/api/student//##value of pk2/
```

So how will i make the query still work and how do i make a url such that it accepts even these as parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.*` (0 or more) instead of `.+` (at least 1 or more):

```
url(r'^api/student/(?P<pk>.*)/(?P<pk2>.*)/$', api.studentList.as_view()),
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile('^api/student/(?P<pk>.*)/(?P<pk2>.*)/$')
>>> pattern.match('api/student/1//').groups()
('1', '')
>>> pattern.match('api/student//1/').groups()
('', '1')
```

Note that, now, in the view you should handle empty string values for `pk` and `pk2`:

```
class studentList(APIView):
    def get(self, request, pk, pk2, format=None):
        student_detail = Student.objects.all()
        if pk:
            student_detail = student_detail.filter(last_name=pk)
        if pk2:
            student_detail = student_detail.filter(campus_id__name=pk2)

        serialized_student_detail = studentSerializer(student_detail, many=True)
        return Response(serialized_student_detail.data)
```

Hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: actually those are not primary keys. I just named them that way ! :D

Comment: i tried this url:  http://localhost:8000/api/student/Campos/57911101/  ... it worked with my previous url but after i changed to * as you mentioned, it was not reteiving anything

Comment: @crozzfire hm, I'm getting `('Campos', '57911101')` on the console, groups are captured..

Comment: i made a small edit. The campus_id in the api is a foreign key relationship to another model...forgot to add the doubleunderscore

Comment: @crozzfire yeah, I've edited the answer too. If `pk2` is not provided, it would be passed to the view as an empty string, you need to check `pk` and `pk2` for being non-empty before passing them to `filter()`.

Comment: yeah so will the query not work if one of them is empty? the point of the search was to have any of the values if not all and still make the query work.

Comment: some help here please?? :D http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30600764/django-saving-many-to-many-entries-using-generic-views