# Django saving many to many entries using generic views

Tags: django, django-views

I have a django model with many to many fields as follows:

```
class Sponsor(CommonInfo, Person):
    signature_code = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department)
    product = models.ManyToManyField(Product, null=True, blank=True, through = 'ProductSponsor')
    accounts = models.ManyToManyField(Account, null=True, blank=True, through = 'AccountSponsor', related_name='sponsoraccounts')
```

and my views has:

```
class SponsorEdit(UpdateView):
    model = Sponsor
    template_name = 'sponsoredit.html'
    fields = ('account', 'department', 'exp_date', 'last_name', 'first_name', 'signature_code', 'comments', 'product', 'accounts')
```

When i am editing an entry by adding some fields in the Many to MAny relationship, i get the following error:

```
AttributeError at /irms/sponsoredit/2
Cannot set values on a ManyToManyField which specifies an intermediary model.  Use irms.ProductSponsor's Manager instead.
```

Where is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

In your model you are using `AccountSponsor` and `ProductSponsor`. They are custom intermediate tables for the relationship, when you save a `Sponsor` object you need to set the intermediate '`ProductSponsor`' and '`AccountSponsor`' objects manually. Something like:

```
ProductSponsor.objects.create(sponsor=SponsorObject, product=ProductObject)
AccountSponsor.objects.create(sponsor=SponsorObject, account=AccountObject)
```